# csv import from unicode to utf8 phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, csv, unicode, utf-8, phpmyadmin

I want to import some Chinese Characters into the MySQL database. But some of the content is omitted, and some is showing non-sense. With the pictures shown below:

What's in the database:

[image]

What's in the excel file:

[image]

Thank you!

Hi, here is the addtional information:

text document

```
巴掌  bāzhang (a slap of the) palm     打  beat    human activities
巴掌  bāzhang (a slap of the) palm     搧  spank   human activities
巴掌  bāzhang (a slap of the) palm     揍  hit human activities
把   bá  tools and objects with a handle 扫帚  broom   tools
把   bá  tools and objects with a handle 锁   lock    man-made
```

show create table

```
CREATE TABLE `table 1` (
 `CL_in_Character` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `CL_in_Pinyin` varchar(14) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `Definition_in_Dictionary` varchar(74) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `Associated_nouns_in_Chinese` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `Associated_nouns_in_English` varchar(38) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `Associated_noun_categories` varchar(38) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Show the definition of your table. Execute `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>` and post results in your question. Also post a few lines of your file in textual form (not an image).

Comment: Is your file being read and inserted as utf8? Is phpMyAdmin displaying in utf8? If you insert one Chinese character into MySQL, can it be displayed correctly?

Comment: if i upload using open document spreadsheet, one of the column of chinese char can be displayed, but one of the column of the char is omitted. yes the file is inserted as utf8.

Comment: Can you please post `create table` as text.

Comment: hi, please see my new edit.

Comment: hi, is there any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell about open document format and phpmyadmin, but you can successfully import your data properly formatted as CSV with

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/your/file.csv' INTO TABLE `table 1`
CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

By properly formatted as CSV I mean

```
CL_in_Character,CL_in_Pinyin,Definition_in_Dictionary,Associated_nouns_in_Chinese,Associated_nouns_in_English,Associated_noun_categories
"巴掌","bāzhang","(a slap of the) palm","打","beat","human activities"
"巴掌","bāzhang","(a slap of the) palm","搧","spank","human activities"
"巴掌","bāzhang","(a slap of the) palm","揍","hit","human activities"
"把","bá","tools and objects with a handle","扫帚","broom","tools"
"把","bá","tools and objects with a handle","锁","lock","man-made"
```

Let's try it

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `table 1` (
    ->  `CL_in_Character` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
    ->  `CL_in_Pinyin` varchar(14) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
    ->  `Definition_in_Dictionary` varchar(74) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
    ->  `Associated_nouns_in_Chinese` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
    ->  `Associated_nouns_in_English` varchar(38) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
    ->  `Associated_noun_categories` varchar(38) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL
    ->  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/utf.csv' INTO TABLE `table 1`
    -> CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> IGNORE 1 LINES;
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from `table 1`;
+-----------------+--------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
| CL_in_Character | CL_in_Pinyin | Definition_in_Dictionary        | Associated_nouns_in_Chinese | Associated_nouns_in_English | Associated_noun_categories |
+-----------------+--------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
| 巴掌            | bāzhang      | (a slap of the) palm            | 打                          | beat                        | human activities           |
| 巴掌            | bāzhang      | (a slap of the) palm            | 搧                          | spank                       | human activities           |
| 巴掌            | bāzhang      | (a slap of the) palm            | 揍                          | hit                         | human activities           |
| 把              | bá           | tools and objects with a handle | 扫帚                        | broom                       | tools                      |
| 把              | bá           | tools and objects with a handle | 锁                          | lock                        | man-made                   |
+-----------------+--------------+---------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: It did help me. Just one thing: LINES TERMINATED BY '\n', should be used with '\r\n' linefeed (in case of using odf)

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem as you and reached this question. Then I've solved it by changing the option in phpmyadmin from

```
Lines terminated with: auto
```

to

```
Lines terminated with: \n
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by copying the whole excel data, and paste as value, then it will recognize the character.