# Can I upload characters like ö to a MYSQL database via SSH?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to upload content to a Wordpress database.

The content is in a CSV file, the upload is done through PHPMYADMIN, and I've set the encoding to UTF8. The upload completes, but the content cuts off whenever it encounters and accented character.

For example, if I uploaded a post with the title: "I love Mötley Crüe," the post will appear on the site, but the title will be "I Love M."

To get around this issue, I was wondering if I could do the upload via SSH/Putty--using the same file but setting the encoding to utf8mb4.

Will this different encoding allow characters like ö and ü through? Or should I be considering a different approach altogether?

Comment: See [MySQL 10 documentation, Chapter 10 Character Sets, Collations, Unicode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset.html)

Comment: @Sam-M - I appreciate the link, but the issue there seems to have been resolved by specifying a character set. In my case, the issue exists even after the character set has already specified. So, I'd like to hear if updating the character set to utf8mb4 will resolve the issue.

Comment: @user2258740 See if this one helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238124/csv-import-from-unicode-to-utf8-phpmyadmin

Comment: @Sam-M - As it turns out the issue wasn't the MYSQL database or the command I was using. It's that the csv file wasn't UTF8. After fixing that, it works correctly whether I set the characters to UTF8 or utf8mb4. Thanks for the context.